# How to set an associated constant from `self` (in rust)

Tags: rust

If i have a trait defined as:

```
pub trait foo {
  const ID: u32;
  ...
```

and a struct defined as:

```
pub struct fooStruct {
  pub id: u32,
  pub name: vec<u8>,
  ...
}
```

when i implement the trait for `fooStruct`, i would like to do something like:

```
impl foo for footStruct {
  const ID: u32 = self.id // self does not work here
}
```

My question is: How can i set my ID const by reading from the struct that is implementing it (if its possible at all)?

Thanks

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible. Can you please elaborate on what exactly it is you're trying accomplish in the first place? It would help us in being able to offer potential alternative solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *How can i set my ID const by reading from the struct that is implementing it (if its possible at all)?*

I do not believe it is possible.

> Like immutable variables, constants are values that are bound to a name and are not allowed to change, but there are a few differences between constants and variables...
>
> ...***constants may be set only to a constant expression***, not the result of a function call or any other value that could only be computed at runtime.

`self.id` is a value computed at runtime time, `const ID: u32 = self.id`  will not work.

Furthermore, `self` exists only in methods.